# Initialize ServiceRegistry in hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate

Since the buildSessionFactory method is deprecated in hibernate 3, we have to create the Session Factory through ServiceRegistry. I have created it like below,

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>((Map)configuration
       .getProperties());
 ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(map)
       .buildServiceRegistry();
```

But it shows me the pmd error like below,

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<? extends String,? extends 
     String>
    - Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized
```

How should i avoid it? It is because of the cast in (Map)configuration.getProperties() right?

Why cant I use generics there like,

```
(Map<String,String>)configuration.getProperties()
```

Also above is the correct way to initialize the Service Registry right because the applySettings() method takes a Map as argument?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use

```
(Map<String,String>)configuration.getProperties()
```

but it generates a warning because at the time the cast is performed (at runtime), it can't be checked that the returned Map has String as type parameters, because that information is not available anymore.  Actually, after compilation, the cast becomes

```
(Map)configuration.getProperties()
```

It seems like although the map may contain only Strings in practice, you shouldn't rely on this and should just use `Map<?,?>`

Comment: the (Map<String,String>) gives me the compile error, Cannot cast from Properties to Map<String,String> and the Map<?,?> gives me compile error The constructor HashMap<String,String>(Map<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?>) is undefined